# Debian Security Updates

Tags: debian, security, upgrade

If I am running an 'unsupported' version of Linux, which is based on Debian, is there any way that I can still get the updates from debian systems as they are released? OR am I stuck waiting on the developers to release patches for the Operating system which I am running ?

Thanks,

Comment: That depends. If it's merely minor changes, adding the Debian security repo to your apt could work. But that's all speculation in the wind. Also, off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

As [SmokeDispenser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/144804/smokedispenser) [says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287779/debian-security-updates#comment502996_287779), it depends on exactly which distribution you're using. In most cases you'd be better off upgrading to a supported release...

You can always try adding the Debian security updates to your `apt` setup, they probably won't break anything. First you need to determine which version of Debian your distribution is based on; then

- if it's based on Debian 7 (Wheezy), use [Wheezy LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using) (only on `amd64`, `armel`, `armhf` and `i386`):

  ```
  echo deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy-security.list
  ```
- if it's based on Debian 8 (Jessie), use the standard security updates:

  ```
  echo deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-security.list
  ```

If it's older than that, you won't get any support from Debian either.

Depending on how your distribution builds upon Debian, you may need to add the standard (non-security) Debian repositories as well; either

```
echo deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy.list
```

for Debian 7, or

```
echo deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
```

for Debian 8.